# How to set the default selection on the currently added item using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code using this code I am inserting an item from one list box to other list box. I need to set the default selection for tagrget list box item when it is added.

please can any body help me out how to set the deafult selection to the list box.

How to set the default selection to the currently added item to the list box

```
 function DoInsert(ind) {
            var sourceIndex = $("#lstAvailableCode").val(); /// Selected Item to add
            var targetIndex = $("#lstCodelist").val(); /// added item to the list box(target list box)
            var success = 0;
            var rightSelectedIndex = $("#lstCodelist").get(0).selectedIndex;
            var functionName = "/Ajax/SaveCodeforInsert";
            if (ind == "plan") {
                functionName = "/Ajax/SaveCodeforInsertForPlan";
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                traditional: true,
                url: functionName,
                async: false,
                data: "ControlPlanNum=" + $("#ddControlPlan").val() + "&LevelNum=" + $("#ddlLevel").val() + "&ColumnNum=" + $("#ddlColumn").val() + "&SourcbaObjectID=" + sourceIndex + "&TargetbaObjectID=" + targetIndex + "&userID=<%=Model.userID%>",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error Adding Code");
                    FinishAjaxLoading();
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == 0) { success = 1; } else { success = data; }
                    FinishAjaxLoading();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you use

```
.focus()
```

Example:

```
$("#lstCodelist").focus();
```

Comment: Thanks, If i want to make that as selected instead of focus?

Comment: what do you mean selected?  do you want to select a value in the listbox? you could use:
$("#<%=lstCodelist.ClientID%>").val("thevalue");

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.focus` in the success callback to set the focus

`$("element").focus()`